# How can I can I count the number of records returned in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, window-functions

I have a table that has a case number and it is joined to a table that is the person attached to the case. Each person can have multiple reports that are in a report table. I want to report a few fields from each of these but I also want to report the total number of reports per person. For example if John Smith has three reports then in the last column for the three records that will populate from the code below I want it to say 3.

Without the count included I have:

```
SELECT C.attr2459 AS [Case Number], INS.attr2750 AS SSN, LE.attr2534 AS [Report Provider]
FROM hsi.rmObjectInstance1131 AS C INNER JOIN 
     hsi.rmObjectInstance1153 AS INS ON C.fk3056 = INS.objectID INNER JOIN 
     hsi.rmObjectInstance1134 AS LE ON INS.objectID = LE.fk2823
WHERE (C.attr2460 = 'Open')
```

C is the case table. INS is for the person and LE is for the report. This runs as expected without error. 
I am just not sure how to get the count of how many reports there is for each person.

Comment: Why the strange table and column names? Looks like this database was designed by extraterrestrials. If I were forced to work with it, I guess the first thing I'd do is write views with proper names (`create view persons as select attr2750 as ssn, attr2749 as last_name, ... from hsi.rmobjectinstance1153` etc.).

Comment: Just working with what I have to work with.

Comment: I'm just saying that working with this database would be a lot easier, much less error-prone and better maintainable, if you (or someone) created such views. This wouldn't even have any negative impact on performance. They would only make your life better :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions, if your database supports them.

I an unsure which column in your resultset represents a *person*; assuming that it is `LE.attr2534`, that would be:

```
SELECT 
    C.attr2459 AS [Case Number], 
    INS.attr2750 AS SSN, 
    LE.attr2534 AS [Report Provider],
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY INS.attr2750) no_records
FROM hsi.rmObjectInstance1131 AS C INNER JOIN 
     hsi.rmObjectInstance1153 AS INS ON C.fk3056 = INS.objectID INNER JOIN 
     hsi.rmObjectInstance1134 AS LE ON INS.objectID = LE.fk2823
WHERE (C.attr2460 = 'Open')
```

Comment: This shows the incorrect count though. I get a number in that last column but for example I'm getting 14 for a person who I know only has 2 records.

Comment: @CassandraDurell: which column in your dataset represents a person?

Comment: INS is the person table and the SSN is the social of the person.

Comment: I think the issue is that sometimes we are missing a SSN for the person and we have to put in all zeros so it thinks that all 00000 are the same person and is returning 14 because there are 14 reports for 00000. Is there a way to have it partition by the SSN and the last name?

Comment: @CassandraDurell: yes. You can play around with the `partition by` clause of the window function to get the result that you expect (without seeing your actual data, I cannot tell).

Comment: I tried to do PARTITION BY INS.attr2750 AND INS.attr2749) because that would be social and last name but it won't take the AND

Comment: Is it just a comma instead of the AND

Comment: @CassandraDurell: yes: `PARTITION BY INS.attr2750, INS.attr2749`

Answer (score 2):

Include 
     COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY INS.attr2750, INS.attr2749) no_records

to get it to count the records by the person's social and last name.